# How can I reverse geocode to get country name of a given state/regione or city name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to find the country name of a given location, for example lets say I know `pennsylvania` how do I find out automatically **United States of America**?

I found a couple of links for reverse geocoding like [this one](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/reverse-geocoding.html) which gives me the full address on click on a map and [this one](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-control-geocoder/) which works while searching. The last one looks more promising as it uses [nomination](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

This is how I place a marker for `pennsylvania`.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([41.203323, -77.194527], 1);
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: 'Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors'
    });
map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    var markers = [];
    var marker1 = L.marker([41.203323, -77.194527],{title:"marker_1"}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Marker 1");
    markers.push(marker1);

    function markerFunction(id){
        for (var i in markers){
            var markerID = markers[i].options.title;
            if (markerID == id){
                markers[i].openPopup();
            };
        }
    }
```

I don't need a marker tho, I'd be fine to simply display the country name on `console.log()` then I will work it out as I only need to get the country name.

[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/ZkC5M/510/)

Comment: Are you able to use the googleapi?

Comment: @CumminUp07 I'm using leaflet :=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use googleapi to get the country code while using leaflet to do your mapping.

```
 $.ajax({ url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=41.203323,-77.194527&sensor=true',
                 success: function(data){
                     var country = data.results[0].address_components[6].long_name;
                     console.log(country);
                 }
        });
```

Comment: hmm this could be promising tho, maybe longer but I could do a mix-match, where I could actually use googleapi to get the country name while using leaflet for the other stuff i need. It's A solution. Thanks

Comment: Nominatim can be used in a similar way, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Examples